# Arabic Currency Name to be move from left to right

Tags: magento-1.9, template, currency, ce-1.9.2.4

I need to move arabic currency name "QAR 149.00" from left to "149.00 QAR" in my Magento 1.9.2.4. Have tried several techniques but none working.

Urgent response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data` folder .

Select the `xml language` file you need, for example it will be the `ar.xml` for Arabic.

Locate this part of code:

```
<currencyFormat>
<pattern>¤ #,##0.00</pattern>
</currencyFormat>
```

.

Change the position of the queer element **¤ from:**

```
<pattern>¤ #,##0.00</pattern>
```

**to:**

```
<pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
```

> *at end clear your cache*

Comment: Well this works in en.xml but not working in de.xml (de means default right?) I have flush magento cache multiple times. Please help

Comment: delete var/cache folder too then check

Comment: It worked now :) thanks a lot awsumm solution

Comment: Its done thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Enable translation inline in *system / configuration / developer* 
and then go to frontend and edit the text. This will allow you to move the sign for currency.